# jQuery ajax inside a loop problem

Tags: jquery, ajax, loops

This js loop script always get the last value of ui_item inside a jquery ajax funciton. How can a catch the correct value of each iteration?

```
for (var i = 0; i <= split_files_cb_value_holder.length - 1; i++){
    var split_values = split_files_cb_value_holder[i].split(':');

    ui_item = split_files_cb_value_holder[i];

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ds/index.php/playlist/check_folder",
        data: "component_type="+$('#component_type').val()+"&value="+split_values[1],
        success: function(msg)
        {
            console.log(ui_item); //ALWAYS GETS THE LAST VALUE
        },
        error: function()
        {
            alert("An error occured while updating. Try again in a while");
        }
    });

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Add `let` before ui_item will solve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an asynchronous function within a for loop in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343340/calling-an-asynchronous-function-within-a-for-loop-in-javascript)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The problem is that the anonymous callback method captures the `ui_item` variable by reference.  Since there is only one variable, it always gets whatever was assigned last to the variable.

You need to wrap the contents of the `for` loop in a function that takes `i` as a parameter, then call the function in the loop.  Each call to the wrapper function will create a separate variable, solving the problem.

For example:

```
function doCheck(i) {
    var split_values = split_files_cb_value_holder[i].split(':');

    var ui_item = split_files_cb_value_holder[i];

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ds/index.php/playlist/check_folder",
        data: "component_type="+$('#component_type').val()+"&value="+split_values[1],
        success: function(msg)
        {
            console.log(ui_item); //Don't always get the last value
        },
        error: function()
        {
            alert("An error occured while updating. Try again in a while");
        }
    });
}

for (var i = 0; i < split_files_cb_value_holder.length; i++) 
    doCheck(i);
```

Comment: Thank you for the correction, but I feel compelled to add a small note. Sometimes tone isn't conveyed well over the internet, and to get a terse comment beginning with "*WRONG*" seemed harsh.

But, I was glad to see your answer and appreciated the correction. +1 from me.

Comment: @awgy: I'm sorry; I didn't mean to be offensive.  However, seeing two identically wrong answers (and one from a >100K user), I wanted to firmly head off the misconception.  (And, I'm exhausted)

Comment: Can this work with an inline function (i.e. don't give a name to the helper function `doCheck()`). Colocated code has its advantages.

Answer (score -6):

Turn async off, it will fix the problem i guess. I mean add this: async:false

Comment: Yes that's a 'quick and dirty' fix causing browser to load slow might even interrupt loading, altogether.

Comment: As an update: async false is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8.  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/