# Several AJAX Calls calling same success function not working

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a question to the behaviour of this AJAX call shown below which I dont understand.

```
var checkBoxes = document.getElementsByName("newInclCheckBox");
for(var i = 0; i<checkBoxes.length; i++
{
  if(checkBoxes[i].checked)
  {
    var name2 = getTabKeyFromDescription(checkBoxes[i].value);
    var tablenr2 = checkBoxes[i].getAttribute("data-tablenr");
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
      if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
      {

        document.getElementById('newIncl_LogBox').innerHTML += xmlhttp.responseText;

      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "../PHPScripts/getInclusions.php?q=add&name1=" + name1 + "&tablenr1=" + tablenr1 + "&name2=" + name2 + "&tablenr2=" + tablenr2, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
}
```

As you can see, the AJAX Call is inside a for-loop and gets called several times while looping through `checkBoxes`.

The PHP-Skript `getInclusions.php` completes each request successfully, but somehow only the last `xmlhttp.responseText` gets written in my LogBox.

I would understand this behaviour if i had written

```
document.getElementById('newIncl_LogBox').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

(without `+=` Operator).

Why is the writing in the logbox not as expected? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asynchronous Process inside a javascript for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488014/asynchronous-process-inside-a-javascript-for-loop), or see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288759/asynchronous-for-cycle-in-javascript or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343340/calling-an-asynchronous-function-within-a-for-loop-in-javascript or search for "asynchronous for loop javascript".

Comment: Make sure you are getting HTML content from server for each ajax call. And i see syntax issue in for loop.
for(var i = 0; i<checkBoxes.length; i++ this should be for(var i = 0; i<checkBoxes.length; i++ **)**

Comment: the missing parenthesis seems to be a typing error. In my code i have it right :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call ajax synchronously in for loop then it will execute one by one like that and use this code in your code as usual.

This is syncronous ajax call example.

```
urllink="../PHPScripts/getInclusions.php?q=add&name1=" + name1 + "&tablenr1=" + tablenr1 + "&name2=" + name2 + "&tablenr2=" + tablenr2;

$.ajax({
    async: "false",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        url: urllink,
        success: function(jsonData) {
            alert("jsonData =" + jsonData);
            return jsonData;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! Even though I don't use JQuery, setting asynchronous to false did the job.
For anyone who faces the same issues:
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp