# TypeError: this.element is null, Rails with Judge gem

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am building simple client side valditation using Judge gem.

Everything worked perfect till I choosed to run validations on "blur" instead of button click.

**Script:**

```
var divs = ["advertisement_age","advertisement_weight","advertisement_region_id","advertisement_height","advertisement_name","advertisement_phone_number","Record_Start_Time",
"Record_End_Time","Record_Start_Time2","Record_End_Time2","advertisement_description", "advertisement_description_ru", "advertisement_terms_of_service"];

    var arrayLength = divs.length;
    var error_count =0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {

     $(document.getElementById(divs[i])).blur(function(){

        judge.validate(document.getElementById(divs[i]), {  // This line causes error
                valid: function(element) {
                  element.style.border = '1px solid green';
                },
                invalid: function(element, messages) {
                  element.style.border = '1px solid red';
                 // alert(messages.join(','));

        }

        });

      });

    }
```

In Mozzila Firebug there isn't any error message when I reload page.
Error shows up when blur event is triggered.

**Error message:**

```
   TypeError: this.element is null

   this.attrValidators = root.JSON.parse(this.element.getAttribute('data-validate')...
```

I don't understand why it crashes at second `document.getElementById(divs[i])` instead of the first if that array is valid?

Any suggestions ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that by the time the `blur` event fires, the `for` loop has exited and the value of `i` will be set to the last value it arrived at when the `for` loop exited. Then, eventually, when the `blur` event fires `judge.validate(document.getElementById(divs[i])` will fail because `i` is not what you expected. One way to fix it is by forming a closure over the value of `i`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  (function(index) { // index is the current i value
    $(document.getElementById(divs[index])).blur(function() {
      judge.validate(document.getElementById(divs[index]), {
        valid: function(element) {
          element.style.border = '1px solid green';
        },
        invalid: function(element, messages) {
          element.style.border = '1px solid red';
          // alert(messages.join(','));
        }
      });
    });
  })(i); // pass i to the immediately executing anonymous function (closure)
}
```

So we put the `$.blur` code inside a closure and pass `i` in. Inside the closure `i` will be called `index`. The value of `index` will be the expected value at the time the loop executed the code, and will remain that way after the loop exits. Notice how inside the `blur` handler we're now using `divs[index]`.

The thing to take away from this particular problem is that the `blur` event handler function is asynchronous and won't evaluate `divs[i]` until the blur event happens which will be at a time after the `for` loop has exited and left the value of `i` at its last value `i == arrayLength - 1`.

Here's some more reading on that: [Calling an asynchronous function within a for loop in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343340/calling-an-asynchronous-function-within-a-for-loop-in-javascript)

Another way to fix this would be to save the element you find with `document.getElementById(divs[i])` and then use `this` inside the handler:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  var field = $(document.getElementById(divs[i]));
  field.blur(function() {
    judge.validate(this, { // `this` is the field element
      valid: function(element) {
        element.style.border = '1px solid green';
      },
      invalid: function(element, messages) {
        element.style.border = '1px solid red';
        // alert(messages.join(','));
      }
    });
  });
}
```

I'd choose the latter solution as it is cleaner. Just wanted to explain the closure thing first.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wish I could give more reputation for this.

Comment: Wouldn't that be easer to use `this` instead of `$(document).getElementById(divs[i])` in the handler? Also the current logic will create quite a lot of handlers, it would be more efficient to delegate the event.

Comment: That's true. I got too excited talking about closures that I neglected to mention that you can just change the `divs` array into a comma separated list of ids (prepending a # to each id) or better yet, give all those divs a class (e.g. `.validateMe`) and just call `$('.validateMe').blur...` which would bind 1 event handler to all the elements at once rendering the loop unnecessary.

Comment: @EdgarsRozenfelds no problem , i'll vote him from your side :P