# Unable to set values in javascript array

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I am unable to set project activities which are inside clientsData.
Here is my scenario

By the time the control reaches inside my callback function of executeSql,  values of i and j are maximum possible values because executeSql() is asynchronous function. 
So when I try to execute following line

```
clientData[i].projects[j].activities = result.rows;
```

it gives me error saying "Cannot read property 'projects' of undefined"

Code snippet

```
    for (var i = 0; i < clientData.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < clientData[i].projects.length; j++) {
            var getActivities = "SELECT * FROM Activity \n\
                                WHERE activityID \n\
                                in \n\
                    (" + clientData[i].projects[j].activityIds + ")";
            tx.executeSql(getActivities, [], function (tx, result) {
                clientData[i].projects[j].activities = result.rows;
                updateClientData(clientData);
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: `j` will probably have changed by the time the async executeSql finishes...

Comment: I understood that, but is there any way I can avoid it?

Comment: Consider using the appropriate array.forEach function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: Yes it helped a lot, I also got some help from following link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343340/calling-an-asynchronous-function-within-a-for-loop-in-javascript