# Pass parameters to dynamically created Gulp task

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am super new to Gulp so might be on the wrong track here but...

I am trying to create tasks dynamically from values in an object. A simple version of my code is:

```
var data = {"v1" : "foo",
            "v2" : "bar",
            "v3" : "foobar"};

var taskList = [];

for(var key in data){
    taskList.push(key);
    gulp.task(key, function(){
        console.log(key, data[key]);
        return;
    });
}

gulp.task("master", taskList);
```

This creates and runs the three tasks as I expected but each one outputs `v3 foobar` and the values `foo` and `bar` are unused.
I'm thinking this is maybe some kind of value vs reference issue and each task is receiving `key` as a reference rather the actual value?

Can anyone shed any light?

Cheers all

Comment: Not a gulp issue, just an issue with async functions in a for loop. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343340/calling-an-asynchronous-function-within-a-for-loop-in-javascript could also be helpful.

Comment: This was indeed the issue and both answers helped to solve it. In the end I actually used the one in the link @AnotherDev posted. Putting the data into an `Array` instead of an `Object` and then using `Array.forEach()` to create the tasks. As always the good folk of stackoverflow deliver the good stuff :)