# Creating array in ES6 with async method calls

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have the following method that I'm trying to complete:

```
  getAllValues: function (callback) {
    this.getCount((count) => { // count is usually 5
      let results = []
      for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        this.getValue(i, (result) => { // getValue() is async and eventually returns a string
          results.push(result)
        })
        if (i == count-1) {
          callback(results)
        }
      }
```

I want `results` to be an array with all of the strings returned by `getValue()`; however, I haven't been able to figure out how to do this. In `callback(results)`, `results` ends up being an empty array, so the pushed values are being dropped somehow

How do I get this to do what I want?

EDIT: I do NOT want to use promises here.

Comment: Are you able to use promises instead? There’s a very convenient `Promise.all` that exists. Doing the same thing otherwise involves keeping track of how many callbacks have been called so far.

Comment: I think this can help you: https://gist.github.com/anvk/5602ec398e4fdc521e2bf9940fd90f84

Comment: If getValue is async then you need to use await to get the result, not just get the promise it returns

Comment: @John - `await` only works if `getValue` returns a promise

Comment: @JosanIracheta - you too assume that getValue returns a Promise, there's no indication that this is the case, since it uses the "callback" pattern, it's highly unlikely to return a Promsie

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm not assuming that it returns a promise but I was hoping that maybe he would consider re-writing his code to use promises

Comment: fair enough @JosanIracheta

Comment: this stackoverflow answer should help and uses no promises: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343340/calling-an-asynchronous-function-within-a-for-loop-in-javascript

Comment: how so @JosanIracheta? there's no logic in that answer regarding when to call the call back ... I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47584358/5053002) is more relevant :p it too uses no Promises, at least, not the first snippet

Comment: @JaromandaX that SO question is about async functions within a for-loop. It's very relevant. But yes, your answer is good too lol ;-)

Comment: It is relevant @JosanIracheta, but the problem the OP has is calling the callback at the wrong time

Comment: Sorry @Jaromanda X, I read the comment in the code and thought that it was referring to an actual async function and not simply something that runs asynchronously in the more traditional node callback style.

Comment: ahh yes, @John - I can see how that happened :p

Answer (score 2):

You're testing for the results completion in the wrong place

```
getAllValues: function(callback) {
    this.getCount((count) => { // count is usually 5
        let results = [];
        let completed = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) { // *** use let instead
            this.getValue(i, (result) => { // getValue() is async and eventually returns a string
                completed ++;
                results[i] = result; // *** note this change to guarantee the order of results is preserved
                if (completed == count) {
                    callback(results)
                }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Note: use let in the for loop, so that `i` is correct inside

don't `push` ... assign to the index, to preserve order of results

and alternative, by having a "promisified" `getValue` (called it `getValuePromise` in the code below)

```
getValuePromise: function(i) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.getValue(i, resolve);
    });
}
getAllValues: function(callback) {
    this.getCount((count) => 
        Promise.all(Array.from({length:count}).map((unused, i) => this.getValuePromise(i)))
        .then(callback)
    );
}
```

Answer (score -2):

What you need to do is use `then()` it will wait for your async function to finish then it will run your callback.

```
getAllValues: function (callback) {
    this.getCount((count) => { // count is usually 5
      let results = []
      for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        this.getValue(i, (result) => { // getValue() is async and eventually returns a string
          results.push(result)
        }).then(function(getValueResults){
            if (i == count-1) {
              callback(results)
            }
        })
      }
```

Comment: I think the problem is that the loop is over before even one result is returned from the async function

Comment: `What you need to do is use then()` assuming `getValue` returns a Promise as well as calling a callback - an unlikely situation, most asynchronous functions do one or the other, not both

Comment: His comment says it is async, so I assumed that it returned a promise...

Comment: async code existed since Brendan Eich first created javascript - Promises have not :p

Comment: `most asynchronous functions do one or the other, not both` - to clarify, there's no reason why it can't do both, other than lack of clarity in code :p