# foreach check if image exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to make the foreach loop on the result return by the ajax. While doing foreach I am checking against each record that image exist or not.

Image Existence Code

```
function imageExists(url, callback) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() { callback(true); };
    img.onerror = function() { callback(false); };
    img.src = url;
}
```

For each loop

```
 hotelImagesText = '<ul class="gallery list-unstyled cS-hidden" id="image-gallery">';
    $.each(hotelImagesArr, (index, item) => {
        imageExists(item, function(exists) {
            if (exists) {
                hotelImagesText += '<li data-thumb="'+hotelImagesArr[index]+'"> 
               <img src="'+hotelImagesArr[index]+'"></li>';
             }
    });
});
    hotelImagesText += '</ul>';
```

When I console it only gives me the above string that has ul. The string inside the imageExists does not concat.

Comment: What does 'exist' show in console?

Comment: if image exists then it shows true and if not exists then false.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an asynchronous function within a for loop in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343340/calling-an-asynchronous-function-within-a-for-loop-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

That's because, even though `$.each` is synchronous, `imageExists` is not and therefore the concatenations happen too late.

What you can do is return `Promise` instances from the latter, and make use of `Promise.all`.

**Demo**:

```js
function imageExists(url) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => resolve(true);
    img.onerror = () => resolve(false);
    img.src = url;
  });
}

const hotelImagesArr = [
  'https://www.sample-videos.com/img/Sample-jpg-image-50kb.jpg',
  'https://www.sample-videos.com/img/Sample-jpg-image-100kb.jpg',
  'https://stackoverflow.com/idonotexist.jpg'
];

let hotelImagesText = '<ul class="gallery list-unstyled cS-hidden" id="image-gallery">';

const checks = hotelImagesArr.map(url => imageExists(url));

Promise.all(checks).then(checksResults => {
  for (let i in checksResults) {
    if (checksResults[i]) {
      hotelImagesText += `<li data-thumb="${hotelImagesArr[i]}"><img src="${hotelImagesArr[i]}"></li>`;
    }
  }

  hotelImagesText += '</ul>';

  console.log(hotelImagesText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is shoowing empty result to me.

Comment: only <ul class="gallery list-unstyled cS-hidden" id="image-gallery"> displays

Comment: @UmairKhan As you can see the sample works. Can you post your updated code (maybe edit the question)?

Comment: should i post in comment ?

Comment: let hotelImagesText = '<ul class="gallery list-unstyled cS-hidden" id="image-gallery">';

if( hotelImagesArrLength > 0 ) {
 const checks = hotelImagesArr.map(url => imageExists(url));

 Promise.all(checks).then(checksResults => {
  console.log(checksResults);
   for (let i in checksResults) {
     if (checksResults[i]) {
       hotelImagesText += `<li data-thumb="${hotelImagesArr[i]}"><img src="${hotelImagesArr[i]}"></li>`;
     }
   }
    
    hotelImagesText += '</ul>';
    });
}

Comment: @UmairKhan Did you also change `imageExists` to return a Promise? Maybe you can post your whole code to https://pastebin.com/

Comment: @UmairKhan Your `console.log` needs to be within `Promise.all`'s callback (above where you put it), along with any code that needs to be executed after all checks have been computed.

Comment: @UmairKhan You're welcome (you can also mark the answer as accepted if you'd like). Good day