# Callback isn't called as many times as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

Employee webpage makes Ajax calls to the node.js web server in a loop. Code as given. All data values are correct. I expect the callback `UpdateTeamArr` to be called n times where n is equal to the loop max - `document.getElementById("deptSelect").options.length`. But its called only once. Thanks for your effort and support.

#### Client side code:

```
for (var i = 1; i < document.getElementById("deptSelect").options.length; i++) {
    var objJSON = {
        "deptid": document.getElementById("deptSelect").options[i].dataset.id,
        "empid": selectedEmployeeId
    }   
    var strJSON = JSON.stringify(objJSON);
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 

    xmlhttp.open("post", "../../GetEmployeesTeams", true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
            UpdateTeamArr(xmlhttp);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
    xmlhttp.send("strJSON=" + strJSON);     
    }
}
function UpdateTeamArr(xmlhttp) {
}
```

#### Server code:

```
app.post('/GetEmployeesTeams', function(req, res) {
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : "127.0.0.1",
    port     : 3306,
    user     : "root",
    password : "root",
    database : "lighting"
});
var strJSON = req.param('strJSON');
var objJSON = JSON.parse(strJSON);

connection.connect();
connection.query("SELECT db_teamemp.teamid, db_department.id AS deptid FROM lighting.db_teamemp, lighting.db_department, lighting.db_team WHERE db_teamemp.empid='" + 
                    objJSON.empid + "' AND db_department.id='" + objJSON.deptid + "' AND db_teamemp.teamid=db_team.id AND db_team.dept=db_department.id;", 
                    function(err, result, fields) {
    if (err)
        throw err;
    else {
        connection.end();
        res.status(200);
        return res.send(result);
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an asynchronous function within a for loop in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343340/calling-an-asynchronous-function-within-a-for-loop-in-javascript)

Comment: This code works fine for me (aside from some deficiencies in other areas), are you sure it shouldn't be `var i = 0` instead of `var i = 1`)

Comment: Try adding console.log statements inside your loop (print `strJSON`) and see if it executes as many times as you think.  Also add one at top of UpdateTeamArr, to confirm how often it's actually called.  Last be aware you seem to have an extra curly brace at the end of the loop - possibly copypaste error.

Comment: Not a duplicate of Calling an asynchronous function within a for loop in JavaScript – @ponury-koste. That talks about closure whereas here its the number of executions.

Comment: @adam - var i = 1 is intentional

Comment: @Elliot Nelson - console logs in the server indicate everything is fine there. They are printed n number of times. Its the client side thats causing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, you are using a `var` here for `xmlhttp`. A var is not block scoped, it's hoisted - that means this single var is used by all calls to `UpdateTeamArr`. I believe you *are* calling the function N times, but with the last response every time.

An easy test of this theory is simply changing `var` to `let` on that line.

Comment: Thank you very much @Elliot Nelson. That sorted it out.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try to perform just a single request to the server by creating a uniq JSONArray with a list containing all Employees id's inside your 'deptSelect'?

This way you send a response with also a list containing the other attributes for the employees in another JSONArray format, that you can iterate in the UpdateTeamArr function

Comment: Good suggestion @PabloQ. I would still like to know why the callbacks aren't executing.