# Javascript: How to loop through an Array while pausing?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, authentication

```
var clientBASE = new User();
var username = ["Username1","Username2"];
var password1 = ["Password1","Password2"];
var arrayLength = username.length;
var i;

for(i=0; i < arrayLength; i++){
    client.logOn({
        "accountName": username[i],
        "password": password1[i],
    });
{

clientBASE.on('loggedOn', function(details) {
    console.log("Logged into Server as " + clientBASE.userID.getUserID());
    clientBASE.setText("Logged in");
    console.log("Logged In");
    clientBASE.logOff();

});

}
```

At the moment the script just currently logs into Username2 and skips username1
The script should log into username1,  run the code, pause, then log into username2 and run the same code.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Java != Javascript

Comment: Java and JavaScript are two different things. When posting questions about JavaScript, do *NOT* put the `java` tag. clientBASE.setText("Logged in"); Extra quotation mark.

Comment: logs in a user, sends a message they are logged in, then logs them out, however at the moment it only logs into username2, or the last of the array, it doesnt log into the individual accounts

Comment: Can you please try running without event listener ClientBASE.on line, performing actions directly in a synchronous way.. Then use try catch if login fails..

Comment: where is the code for `clientBase` and `User`

Comment: the code runs it just always takes the last in the array as username and password, i thought this was more to do with a logic error than anything, i tried without logOff(), and still same result

Comment: so instead of going through both both elements in the array it only uses the last one and prints it twice

Comment: @MikeJunior we don't know what `logOff()`, `logOn()`, `ClientBase`, or `User` are supposed to do nor what their code looks like. Edit your question to include the code for those and also include the purpose of the script. These are all things that are required for a post on StackOverflow. No worries though, I did the same thing my first time.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343340/calling-an-asynchronous-function-within-a-for-loop-in-javascript