# how to rewrite with callback for promised result

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

There is a function to generate a string and return it if it is in the User table.

```
 function generateFortToken(len) {
       let rs; 

        rs = randomstring.generate(len);
        User.findOne({where: {fort_token: rs}})
                .then(result => {
                    console.log("hit is : ", result);
                    if (!result) //need to return rs. but HOW?
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log("Error search for fort token : ", err.message);
            });        

}
```

This `generateFortToken` is in module `helper` and is called from parent function like this:

```
user.fort_token = helper.generateFortToken(20);
```

This code does not work as many online posts pointed out since `findOne` returns a promise. But I am having hard time to rewrite it with callback to return the value of token generated.

Comment: How about at least adding a tag with the relevant language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem with the code below:

```
generateFortToken : async function(len) {
    let rs, bs, lp = true; 
    while (lp) {
        rs = randomstring.generate(len);
        await new Promise(next => {
            User.findOne({where : {fort_token : rs}})
                       .then(result => {
                            if(!result) lp = false;
                            next();
                       })
                       .catch(err => {
                            console.log("Error search for fort token : ", err.message);
                            //next();
                       });
        });

   }
   return rs;
},
```

In parent function:

```
user.fort_token = await helper.generateFortToken(20);
```

Inspired by `Fernando Carvajal` reply to [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343340/calling-an-asynchronous-function-within-a-for-loop-in-javascript).

Answer (score 1):

The code you came up with is fine, but it can be improved. In particular, you've fallen into to the [Promise constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25569299/179125). In short, you're constructing a new promise (`await new Promise(next => User.findOne(...))`) when you can use the promise returned by `User.findOne` directly:

```
async function generateFortToken(len) {
  for (let rs;; rs = randomstring.generate(len)) {
    try {
      if (await User.findOne({ where: { fort_token: rs }})) {
        return rs;
      }
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log('Error search for fort token : ', err.message);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I was using `await` for findOne and somehow it didn't work for me. I didn't find an example of such online either.