# How to asynchronous call function with the result of foreach loop

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I have a function that loops over an array of objects and builds an object depending on some parameters. It should return the build object
which represents a state object of a component that I will set. However, I would like to use the `Array.foreach` but I have no idea how to call the function after the foreach loop is done.

The function looks something like this:

```js
 buildStateObject= (someArray: Array) => {
    let stateobject= {};
    someArray.foreach(item => {
      switch (item.Someparameter) {
        case 1:
          stateobject.someProp1= item.message;
          break;
        case 2:
          stateobject.someProp2= item.message;
          break;
        // code omitted
      }

    });
     return stateobject;
  };
```

and in my component I have something like this which obviously does not work :

```js
if(someJson.jsonArray)
    this.setState(this.buildStateObject(someJson));
```

So what I am looking for is something like this:

```js
Promise.all(buildStateObject).
  then((theResultObjectMaybe)=>{this.setState(theResultObjectMaybe);})
```

I tried to figure this out but I was not able to. I am also not sure if this is a good practice todo.

**[Edit]**

@PaulJanicki thank you for pointing the error out. There were just type errors. However one error you pointed out was also in my code which results in a `Unhandled promise rejection` and I assumed this was because the `forEac`h was async and the result was not yet processed.

The problem was a type error `foreach` instead of the correct `forEach`

Comment: You are returning the `stateobject` in the `forEach` (also - camelcase), but you'd have to return it after the loop is finished, so the `buildStateObject`-function actually returns something

Comment: I think this might be helpful to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343340/calling-an-asynchronous-function-within-a-for-loop-in-javascript/50291886#50291886

Comment: @ThomasAltmann you are right, I fixed the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the return statement outside of the forEach method, in the `buildStateObject` function. Also `forEach` should be camelCase.

```js
 function buildStateObject(someArray) {
  let stateobject = {};
  someArray.forEach(item => {
    switch (item.someparameter) {
      case 1:
        stateobject.someProp= item.message;
        break;
      case 2:
        stateobject.someProp= item.message;
        break;
      // code omitted
    }
  });
  
  return stateobject;
}

function setState(state) {
  console.log(state);
}

var someJson = [{
  message: 'first',
  someparameter: 1
}, {
  message: 'second',
  someparameter: 2
}]

setState(buildStateObject(someJson))
```

Also consider that `stateobject.someProp` will be overwritten with each loop execution, not sure if that's the intended behaviour.

Comment: what does returning from the forEach do?

Comment: @DanStarns, of course nothing, it was just a leftover from the original code. Thanks for pointing this out! Removed