how to pass data from nested ajax to parent ajax
i am working in codeigniter 3 i have a table in my database wit name tests and another table results. i retrieve data from tests table by ajax and then get results from result table by nested ajax to fill a . every thing works fine but i only get result in last low of html table. i need help
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#test_btn").click(function(){
    var saleid = $("#lbid").val();
    if (saleid)
    {
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url:"<?php echo base_url('lab_tests/get_saletests_byid')?>",
        data: {id:saleid},
        success: function(result){
        var getdata = JSON.parse(result);
        console.log(getdata);
            // html table is populated.         
        for(var i = 0; i < getdata.length; i ++) {                              
        var table=document.getElementById("testTable");     
        var row=table.insertRow(-1);
        var cell1=row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2=row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3=row.insertCell(2);
        var cell4=row.insertCell(3);
        var cell5=row.insertCell(4);
        cell2.className='classPrice';
        cell1.innerHTML= getdata[i]['name'];                                
        cell2.innerHTML=getdata[i]['price'];        
        cell3.innerHTML=getdata[i]['test_id']; 
        cell4.innerHTML=0; 
        var tid = getdata[i]['test_id']; 
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url:"<?php echo base_url('lab_tests/get_results_byid')?>",
                data: {id:saleid, testid:tid},
                success: function(res){
                var getdat = JSON.parse(res);
                console.log(getdata);
                cell4.innerHTML = getdat[0]['result']
                }
                });
                cell5.innerHTML=cell5.innerHTML+'<input type="button" class="btn_small" 
                value="remove" onclick="delrow(this);" />';                         
                            
            
                        }
                        
                    }

here i have omitted some brackets but data is retrieved correctly.
i need my out put as
test name        test id         price       result        action

glucose            80            100          274            del

urea               96            200           61            del

creatinine         97            200           1.7           del

but actually i get
test name    test id   price  result    action
-------------------------------------------------
glucose    |   80    |   100 |            del

urea       |   96    |   200 |            del

creatinine |  97     |  200  |  1.7       del


Ajax requests are asynchronous, so by the time your first inner ajax call returns, the loop will have already finished and the cell4.innerHTML will refer to cell 4 in the last row of the table. The answer here may be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343340/calling-an-asynchronous-function-within-a-for-loop-in-javascript
But since your inner ajax call seems to only be returning one result for each row, it might be easier to join the tests and results tables together in sql, and then get and print the resulting table with a single ajax call.
