# Passing div element to success callback jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback

I am using lis to obtain a list of `<li>` from my DOM, and in each LI  and update the projectPhoto after the ajax call. But my "li" in the callback function always referring to the last item in `lis`, is there any way to overcome this, or such as pass as value ?

p/s: I am pretty sure this has been discussed before just that I can't reach it with the right terminology. Apology in advance.

```
var lis = $('.porject_list li');
   for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {

        var li = lis.eq(i);
var projectId = li.attr('data-project-id');


            $.get("/webapi/projects/projectphoto/" + projectId, function (res) {
                $("img", li).attr('src', res);
            });
    }
```

Comment: Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687679/jquery-ajax-inside-a-loop-problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this (Just wrap the `ajax` call in a function)

```
(function(current){
    $.get("/webapi/projects/projectphoto/" + projectId, function (res) {
        $("img", current).attr('src', res);
    });
})(li);
```

**Update :**

I didn't notice `var li = lis.eq(pos);`, what is this, anyways, you can use

```
var li = lis[i];
```

to get the current `li` in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

you used jquery so you can used [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) of jquery. try this code if it can help

```
$(".porject_list li").each(function(i, elem) {
    var projectId = $(this).attr('data-project-id');
    var $li = $(this);
    $.get("/webapi/projects/projectphoto/" + projectId, function (res) {
         $li.find("img").attr('src', res);
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good reference for you.

http://api.jquery.com/each/