# jQuery Pass Counter Variable to POST inside for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

My Code is as such:

```
for (var i=0; i < numaccounts; i++) { 
    $.post('assets/ajax/multi-save.php', appointments[i], function(data) {
      alert(appointments[i]);
      alert(appointments[0]);
    });
}
```

the problem seems to be with my array appointments.  The second with the fixed offset of 0 displays fine. The one using 'i' displays as 'undefined'. If I alert(i) it is always '2'.

Comment: can you post the array 'appointments' also? also what is ```numaccounts```? should it be ```numaccounts.length```?

Comment: The array isn't the issue because if I set the offset manually it displays in the same space.  The issue is how do I get the i counter inside the .post function. It only seems to show up as the terminating value of 2.

Comment: and what is numaccounts?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, all it took was a little more searching:

[jQuery ajax inside a loop problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687679/jquery-ajax-inside-a-loop-problem)

Explains the problem and gives the solution.